# How to integrate video player with quality option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-player

Want to integrate video player with diffrent quality option with below url in flutter
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Also, guide me on video player and streaming concept.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use this plugin to ``[Video-player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) to achieve it. They provide a option for video playback controller and video player options.